# How can i implement Feature Like “Precache Map Area” as like Google Map

Tags: android, google-maps

Can I Implement Feature Like

> "Cache Google Map Tile"

or

> "Precache Map Area"

which is in Google Maps?

In Latest Google Maps Update, There is a option like `"Precache Map Area"` So i want to implement this Feature in My Own Application and on My Own Device. So can i Do this Using Google Android Open Source Code which is available on android Developer Website??

Basically want to see google map in offline mode, means i want to get Map from Cache Map Tile when GPRS or Wifi is not there.

So can i save this google map tile to cache and use this map in future.?? Please Suggest me the way so if possible than i will proceed for next.

Answer (score 0):

No, and we can see you got the same answer and the reason why on a newsgroup last year:
http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.handhelds.android.devel/192411/match=precache+map+area